# invalid syntax with elif and else

Tags: python

Whenever I try to use `elif` and `else` after `if`, it says invalid syntax. For example:

```
if number == "1"
print("123213")

elif number == "2"
print("23423")

else number == "3"
print("324234")
```

Comment: Yes, there are multiple errors there. Have you considered looking at the instructions? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Answer (score 3):

There are three mistakes

- `:` is missing
- Indent is missing
- else cannot have a conditional

The code can be re-written as

```
if number == "1":
    print("123213")

elif number == "2":
    print("23423")

elif number == "3":
    print("324234")
```

Complete working code

```
number = input("Enter a number - ")

if number == "1":
    print("123213")

elif number == "2":
    print("23423")

elif number == "3":
    print("324234")
```

Output

```
Enter a number - 1
123213
```

Comment: @IndegoDragon Post the traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15
    elif classchoice == "2":
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IndegoDragon That's not from the code you have posted. If it is from other place edit the question.

Comment: Possible solution: remove the empty lines or make sure the number of tabs there is the same as the previous lines.

Comment: well i know, i just used number as an example

Comment: @IndegoDragon It works perfectly for me. Have you copied the code properly?

Comment: number = input("Enter a number")if number == "1":
    print("123213")

elif number == "2":
    print("23423")

elif number == "3":
    print("324234")

Comment: @IndegoDragon Most probably, As it does not come under the purview of this question, you will have to [Ask another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Do accept this as an answer, and ask a separate question. You will get better answers. :)